# TypeError: 'TreeNode' object is not iterable when popping from a deque

Tags: binary-tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm working on LeetCode problem [2096. Step-by-step from a binary tree to another](https://leetcode.com/problems/step-by-step-directions-from-a-binary-tree-node-to-another/):

> You are given the `root` of a **binary tree** with `n` nodes. Each node is uniquely assigned a value from `1` to `n`. You are also given an integer `startValue` representing the value of the start node `s`, and a different integer `destValue` representing the value of the destination node `t`.
>
> Find the **shortest path** starting from node s and ending at node `t`. Generate step-by-step directions of such path as a string consisting of only the **uppercase** letters `'L'`, `'R'`, and `'U'`. Each letter indicates a specific direction:
>
> - `'L'` means to go from a node to its **left child** node.
> - `'R'` means to go from a node to its **right child** node.
> - `'U'` means to go from a node to its **parent** node.
>
> Return *the step-by-step directions of the **shortest path** from node* `s` *to node* `t`.

This is a solution I took from YouTube:

```
class Solution(object):
    def getDirections(self, root, startValue, destValue):

        def lca(node,p,q):
            if not node:
                return None
            if node.val == p or node.val==q:
                return node
            l = lca(node.left,p,q)
            r = lca(node.right,p,q)

            if l and r: 
                return node
            else: 
                return l or r
        
        get_lca = lca(root,startValue,destValue)
        q = collections.deque((get_lca,""))
        count_setp = 0
        despath = ""
        while q:            
            node, path = q.popleft()
            if node.val == startValue:
                count_setp = len(path)
            if node.val == destValue:
                despath = path
            if node.left:
                q.append((node.left,path+"L"))    
            if node.right:
                q.append((node.right,path+"R"))
        return 'U'*count_setp + despath
```

And this code works for them. But when I submit the code, I get this error:

> TypeError: 'TreeNode' object is not iterable
>         node, path = q.popleft()

Why does this happen on me? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've not initialised your deque correctly. The constructor expects an iterable, which you have given, but you wanted to have a queue with *one* element that is a tuple, but instead the tuple was iterated, resulting in *two* entries in the deque: a node and an empty string.

Then when `popleft` is executed, a node is popped, which obviously cannot be tuple-assigned to two names.

So change to:

```
    q = collections.deque([(get_lca,"")])
```